# Import csv file into keychain?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keychain, icloud

I changed from Chrome to Safari. My passwords are all in chrome. In the latest Chrome Canary version, there's an option to export saved passwords into a csv file. But how can I import this file into my keychain?
The csv file has headers `name,url,username,password`

Thanks a lot